# Allocating an array, using a for loop to initialize given any allocated size

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, sizeof, allocation

```
    int *p_numbers;
    p_numbers = malloc((sizeof *p_numbers) * 10);
    if (p_numbers == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(p_numbers) / sizeof(*p_numbers); i++) {
        printf("-> %p\n\n", p_numbers);
        p_numbers[i] = 0;
    }
```

looking for an operation that would find the size of the allocated array so that this for loop could work with any allocated size, as opposed to just i < 10.

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

my current attempt is just getting 8 for the sizeof(p_numbers) and not 40 like I expected, but sizeof(*p_numbers) returns the type size like I expected.

my guess is that sizeof(p_numbers) returns 8 because a pointers to an int is
2 ints total in size (itself and what its pointing to).
but I don't know how I would get it to sizeof the allocated size, and not just the native number.

I'm a beginner so.. I imagine there is utility in this, please tell me if there isn't.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Just save the value `10` in a variable/define and use it for the `malloc()` as well as your loop. If your pointer has a size of 8 bytes then you are on a 64-bit machine and all pointers, not matter the type will have that size, since pointers are just addresses in memory. This means that `sizeof(void*) == sizeof(int*) && sizeof(int*) == sizeof(char*)` and whatever else pointer will be true.

Comment: When you have a pointer, the pointer is all you have. The compiler have no idea what the pointer is pointing to, if it's pointing to the first element of an array, or the possible size of such an array. Always save the size (number of elements) you allocate in a variable, and use that variable whenever the size is needed.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131925/getting-the-size-of-a-malloc-only-with-the-returned-pointer)

Comment: The solution is most probably to remove the magic `10` and replace it with `#define SOMETHING_MEANINGFUL (10)`  or `enum { SOMETHING_MEANINGFUL = 10 };` - then use `SOMETHING_MEANINGFUL` both when allocating and looping.

Comment: _looking for an operation that would find the size of the allocated array_... Well, you did that already: that was your code that computed the expression you passed to `malloc` as the size of the block you need. Just use it. You wrote `malloc((sizeof *p_numbers) * 10);` So `10` is the size. What about `size=10` and then `malloc(size)`. Then use `size` in the loop...

Answer (score 2):

The expression `sizeof(p_numbers) / sizeof(*p_numbers)` does not work for pointers, only for defined arrays.  You cannot determine the size of the allocated array from the pointer, you must keep track of the allocated size with a separate variable or use the constant `10` as you did for the allocation.